# Angular loop through array and collect Observables with forkJoin

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I have a method which gets an array of strings `(tagArray: string[])` as input. Now I loop through this array and perform a search (via POST) to the server to check if the tag is already in the database.

If the tag exists, the corresponding tag object is returned by the server and stored in another array `(searchFilter: { tags: Tag[] }[])`.

If it does not exist, another POST request is made to the server to store the missing tag in the backend and after that, the tag object created gets stored in `searchFilter['tags']`.

```
performTagMatching(tagArray: string[]):any {
  for(let tagElem of tagArray) {
    // create search request for tag lookup
    const searchRequest: SearchRequest = { term: tagElem, operation: 'exact'};

    this.apiClientService.findTagByTitle(searchRequest).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        // Check tag search result for existence of tag
        if(response.length == 0) {
          // No tag found -> create tag and add to search tag list
          this.searchFilter['tags'].push(this.saveNewTag(tagElem));
        } else {
          // Tag found -> add to search tag list
          this.searchFilter['tags'].push(response[0]);
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

How can I put this in a forkJoin so that I can return the Observable of the forkJoin?

I have two problems here:

1. I need the 'tagElem' in the response which I can't access anymore after I left the for-loop
2. I don't know how I can push the Observables into an array an return that to the method caller

Answer (score 1):

separate your http call from the for loop and call it as a separate function.

```
performTagMatching(tagArray: string[]): any {
    for (let tagElem of tagArray) {
        // create search request for tag lookup
        const searchRequest: SearchRequest = {
            term: tagElem,
            operation: 'exact'
        };

        this.callMactchFunc(tagElem)
    }
}

private callMactchFunc(tagElem) {
    this.apiClientService.findTagByTitle(searchRequest).subscribe(
        (response) => {
            // Check tag search result for existence of tag
            if (response.length == 0) {
                // No tag found -> create tag and add to search tag list
                this.searchFilter['tags'].push(this.saveNewTag(tagElem));
            } else {
                // Tag found -> add to search tag list
                this.searchFilter['tags'].push(response[0]);
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: But my problems remains: how can I put all requests into a forkJoin and still access the tagElem when subscribing to the forkJoin later?